# Grails: In migrating/updating databases, what is the MD5SUM for?

Tags: mysql, database, grails, md5

Probably a rookie question, so have patience.

When I use grails dbm-update-sql I get a generated sql file to update the database to match my domain classes. In the generated SQL file There are INSERTS into the DATABASECHANGELOG.

```
INSERT INTO `DATABASECHANGELOG` (`AUTHOR`, `COMMENTS`, `DATEEXECUTED`,     
`DESCRIPTION`, `EXECTYPE`, `FILENAME`, `ID`, `LIQUIBASE`, `MD5SUM`, 
`ORDEREXECUTED`) VALUES ('Patrick (generated)', '', NOW(), 'Drop Table',
 'EXECUTED', 'changelog.rel-5.4.1.groovy', '1433448105636-5', '2.0.5', 
'3:cf84c26c2f0b5053788ecaad7fac2988', 647);
```

Obviously this is handy to keep a history of changes, but I have the following questions.

What is the MD5SUM for? And what is it hashing to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5SUM is created by hashing the actual script, so if you change it after it has been already executed, you will get an error.